# A file prepared by one spring batch job is not accessible to other for deletion

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement where I have to prepare a file using one job and another job which runs once a day will send the file to external system and delete/or move from the location. When this job tries to delete/or move the file it can't access it.

I tried setting writable to true when file is created. Running jobs on separate times (Running one job at a time). Tried adding "delete" as a step to the same job as well. Nothing worked.
I am using `file.delete()`. Also tried `Files.deleteIfExists()`.

I suspect the first job is not assigning proper permissions but don't know a way around it set permissions in spring batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question . Hope it helps someone. 
Issue was the last ItemWriter was holding the resources because I was using the composite writer. While using CompositeWriter beforeStep, afterStep methods are “hidden”. You have to call them explicitely. I selected the approach to write a custom writer which will explicitely call writer.close().

Adding afterStep method and calling super.close() should also work. Though I have nit tries that out.

Answer (score 0):

Are these jobs run by the same user?   i.e.  Same user and permissions?

Also what is the actual error message?  Does it say permissions denied?  If so they it is likely an OS restriction not Spring Batch/Java limitation.

An easier solution would be to just add a step to the first job to send the files are part of the job and drop the job that just transfers the files.

Comment: Hi Brian, it was actually a “permissions denied” issue. I used Files.deleteIfExists to check actual error. The last ItemWriter in the flow, after all the processing was not releasing the file resource. I had to write overridden write() which will close the writer manually. Though it was not an option for me, I tried adding a step to the first job but writer was still holding the resource.